# <spyOnProperty> : isInCreateMode is not declared configurable

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, mobx

I have an Angular 15 application and I'm using Karma for Unit testing along with **Mobx** as the `StateStore`.

I'm mocking the following mobx code in **Karma**/**Jasmine**:

```
@computed get isInCreateMode(): boolean {
   return this.currentMode === 'CREATE';
}
```

With `spyOnProperty`:

```
spyOnProperty(stateStore, 'isInCreateMode')
   .and.returnValue(false);
```

And I get this error:

> `isInCreateMode` is not declared configurable

What is the problem?

Comment: add `configure({ safeDescriptors: false });` after the imports in the stateStore and it works 